# help me to understand this part of the book on finite fields

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, finite-fields

in the book that is reading, has the following excerpt:

"Each such $f$  has $\deg(f)$ distinct nonzero roots in E ,and each  root $\beta$ of $f$ has as its characteristic polynomial  over $\mathbb{F}_q$ the polynomial
$f(x)^\tfrac{s}{\deg(f)} = x^s -c_{1}x^{s-1}...+(-1)^{s}c_s$."

The polynomial in question is monic and irreducible in $ \mathbb{F}_q $ and $E$ is an extension of this finite field. I believe that the characteristic polynomial related to a root $\beta$ of $f$ is the characteristic polynomial of the linear transformation matrix $ T: E \to E$ defined by $ T(x) = x\beta  $. My question is: Why is this characteristic polynomial just $ f (x)^\tfrac {s}{\deg (f)} $?

Ps: $\deg(f)$ divides $s$.

Comment: I believe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2615043/11619) is an earlier version of the same question, but I'm not 100% sure that I'm parsing it right. Anyway, you should not reask the same question here. Never. If there is no answer you should edit the first version and improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the minimal polynomial of the matrix $T$ is just the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $E$, which is $f$.  So, if the roots of $f$ are $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_d$, the characteristic polynomial of $T$ must be $(x-\beta_1)^{e_1}\dots(x-\beta_d)^{e_d}$ for some exponents $e_1,\dots,e_d\geq 1$.  Since the characteristic polynomial has coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_q$, the exponents $e_1,\dots,e_d$ must all be equal (for instance, you can see this by Galois theory: $Gal(E/\mathbb{F}_q)$ permutes $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_d$ transitively while fixing the characteristic polynomial).  That means the characteristic polynomial is actually $f^e$ for some exponent $e$.  Since the characteristic polynomial must have degree $[E:\mathbb{F}_q]$ (which I assume is what you mean by $s$), the exponent $e$ must be $[E:\mathbb{F}_q]/\deg(f)$.

Comment: The T transformation I defined so used a $ f $ root, how can you speak of T's characteristic polynomial and put all these roots together?